# Solving for matrices AB=CA

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

We have square matrices A, B, C such that = and both main diagnols of B and C are all 0's. Is there any way of solve for A given B and C?

I am trying to avoid using the Kronecker product matrix equation identity.

Answer (score 5):

By the theory of [the Sylvester equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation), there is a nonzero solution if and only if $B$ and $C$ have a common eigenvalue.  If $\lambda$ is such an eigenvalue, with eigenvectors $u$ and $v$ for $B^T$ and $C$ respectively, then
$A = v u^T$ satisfies $AB - CA = \lambda v u^T - \lambda v u^T = 0$.

Comment: Is the result A invertible?

Comment: becuase it seems like the resulting matrix is singular

Comment: $v u^T$ has rank $1$, so is singular unless the dimension is $1$.  If $A$ is invertible, $B = A^{-1} C A$ which says $B$ and $C$ are [similar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity).